# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Getting "Reference Error: WL is not defined"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I am using worklight 6.1.

I am not able to call adapter procedure from another HTML page (i.e. page other than index.html). `WL.Client.invokeProcedure` is not getting executed.

I get this error:

> REFERENCE ERROR: WL is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Worklight is a Single Page Application.
This means you **cannot** "change pages" using methods such as

- `window.location.href`
- `window.open("onsubmit.html","_self");`
- `<a href="onreg.html"`
- and similar

This is mentioned in the documentation:

- [Creating your first Worklight application](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/02_01_Creating_your_first_Worklight_application.pdf) (slide #18)
- [Building a multi-page application](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/03_02_Building_a_multi_page_application.pdf)

Once you change page like that, you **lose** the Worklight context (= references to the framework), and your application will **stop** functioning.

The following are sample projects demonstrate how to navigate between pages using jQuery and jQuery Mobile:

- [JQM_multipage_load_changePage.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4kocwo205s049b/JQM_multipage_load_changePage.zip) - uses either `.load` or `.changePage`
- Sample project by IBM Worklight: [Multipage app](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/BuildingMultiPageApplicationProject.zip)

It doesn't matter if your project uses a 3rd party framework or not. It is only so you will *understand the concept*.

Comment: Actually through the other html page,i Wanna call the adapter procedure(i.e.interactivity with the database and not with other pages..i am not able to execute this:                             var result= WL.Client.invokeProcedure({
    adapter : 'DB2',
    procedure : 'addDB2',
    parameters : [a,d,b,e,c,g]
    
}, {
    onSuccess : function(result)
    {
    alert("login Success"); 
   window.open("onsubmit.html","_self");
   
     },
    onFailure : function(result){alert("login Failure");}
    });

Comment: Calling adpter procedure means using Worklight API. I will not work if you have between pages, ulness you do it as suggseted. Just provide your project....

Comment: Idan Adar-->I have developed multiple html pages for creating the GUI for the application.I can use WL.Client.invokeProcedure() method to connect to sql adapter only in index.html..Y cant i use it for other html pages for the sql connectivity?Can u pls help me with some code-- the way i can approach sql adapter and execute query from different html pages?

Comment: Please check your Facebook Account.I have send you a message.

Comment: I have reviewed your project, as suspected - you did not heed my adise and use things like " window.open("onsubmit.html","_self");", which as said, will make your app fail working.